# What is the connection between The Phantom Menace (1999) and The Shadow (1994)?

Tags: star-wars, reference, the-phantom-menace, the-shadow

### Introduction

Today, I was leafing" through the IMDb page of the 1994 movie The Shadow. I stumbled across the [Connections](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111143/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) page and found, to my utter surprise, that Star Wars Episode 1: The Phantom Menace, is listed as a connection. According to the page, The Shadow is referenced in The Phantom Menace, but I find that highly doubtful.

### Question

**What, if any, is the connection between The Shadow (1994) and Star Wars Episode 1: The Phantom Menace?**

### References

I've linked to the Connections page of The Shadow above, but below is a screenshot for convenience:

[image: Screenshot of The Shadow Connections page on IMDb]

Comment: It should be noted that the *Phantom Menace*'s [corresponding 'references' list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/movieconnections#references) on IMDb includes many titles other than *The Shadow* (like *Casablanca*, *Batman* and *Black Rain*) that are left unexplained. It basically means a user thought some scene in TPM was influenced by this movie somehow, but without that user's explanation, it'd be hard to know *for certain* what they meant.

Comment: My guess is the comparison of Jedi Mind Tricks and the Shadow's ability to Cloud Men's Minds. I'd have to rewatch ep 1 to be sure, and I never will.

Comment: @Longspeak See my comment to Mateus' answer. The mind trick was already shown in *A New Hope* (1977) and was merely repeated in TPM. *The Shadow* is from 1994.

Comment: @Walt yeah but this was some random users edit on IMdb, with no explanation offered, so we're really only guessing what the heck that person was thinking.

Comment: We are literally duplicating IMDB with this trivia... voted to close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Connections" section in IMDB is meant to cover explicit connections between the two movies, such as:

- characters in the later movie watch or discuss the earlier movie.  For example, in *The Martian* (2015), Mitch Henderson (played by Sean Bean) talks about *The Lord Of The Rings* (2001), without mentioning that Sean Bean played a major character in it.
- one movie is a prequel or sequel to the other.  For example, *Die Hard* (1988) was technically a sequel to *The Detective* (1968).
- both movies come from the same source material.  For example, both *Kiss Me, Kate* (1953) and *10 Things I Hate About You* (1999 ) were based on the 1592 play *The Taming of the Shrew*.

They are not literary or thematic connections, similar genres, or other subjective judgements like that.

I think what you are seeing in this case is a data error.

Comment: Not the 'references' section, though. See the examples [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/movieconnections#references) and some of their explanations.

Comment: while i like the detail in this answer, i have a hard time accepting it as the answer since you didn't seem to determine whether there was a connection or not, but rather share what seems to be your opinion.

Comment: @DForck42 -- the Connections page lists it _Phantom_ as "referencing" _The Shadow_.  Under the usual rules, that would mean that a character in _Phantom_ mentions _The Shadow_, or has a poster of it or some similar explicit reference.  Obviously, that's impossible.  Sometimes, the rules are relaxed, and allow for metatexual references (the way the finale in _Brazil_ quotes the famous Odessa Steps sequence in _Battleship Potemkin_), but that seems unlikely.  As I said, a data error.

Comment: to further support the data error theory, the other options have a description of the reference listed: this one does not.

Comment: I cannot prove a negative.  All the reasons I can think of to assert that there is a link between the two movies are implausible or improbable.  If you have another reason, give it; otherwise please comment on someone else's answer.